# Why does this Depth-first search produce a NullPointerException?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, binary-tree

I have a short snippet of code to produce a depth-first search of an arbitrary binary search tree. This is my code:

```
public void printByDepth()
{
    Queue<BinaryNode<T>> queue = new LinkedList<BinaryNode<T>>();
    BinaryNode<T> current = this;
    queue.add(current);
    while(!queue.isEmpty()){
        current = queue.remove();
        System.out.println(current.element);
        if(current.left != null)
            queue.add(current.left);
        if(current.right != null) // had an extra semicolon here, fixed
            queue.add(current.right);
    }
}
```

It's a pretty standard queue approach, but for some reason line 8 ( `println(current.element)` ) produces an NPE. The tree I am using should produce the following DF output: `F B G A D I C E H`. I've done this exactly on paper and I should never get current = null or queue.isEmpty() = true before I've traversed the entire tree (in this case at least) so I'm not sure why this is happening. None of the nodes have null content.

In addition, interestingly, if I change the while condition to `while(current != null)` I do not get an NPE but the output is : `F B G A D I` , it is missing the last level's elements.

I'm sure there something simple I'm missing... any hints?

EDIT: Runaway semicolon =( Thanks, Roger.

Comment: Your best bet is to single-step through the code with a debugger.

Comment: The last `current = queue.peek();` should be redundant.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Lawrey : Oops, it is. I tried to do some debugging by hand and forgot to remove it.

Comment: Does your code print anything at all before the NPE?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is with:

```
if(current.right != null);
        queue.add(current.right);
```

See your semicolon (;) on the if? This basically means:
if current.right is not null, then do nothing. After that, always add current.right to the queue (even if null).

If you auto format your code this would be easier to see as your indention now falsely suggest that the adding of current.right belong to the if statement.

Comment: My God... Scary... I was already thinking of a compiler bug. Nice catch. +1

Comment: Darn it! This just reminds me not to try this stuff so early in the morning.

Thanks for the keen eye!

Comment: @user991710 ... or it reminds you to ALWAYS use braces like Java Code Conventions advise us to do so.

Comment: +1: Also you should use the IDEs code formatter, instead of formatting the code your self.  This will save you some work and make these sort of problems obvious. My IDE warns if you use "Suspicious indenting" like this.

Comment: @Fatal : That too, but no braces is just so much more elegant. And thank you Peter, that's a piece of advice I haven't paid enough attention too. Time to change that.

Edit: Well actually... I did have auto-format on! Just, on my old laptop. I had just installed the JDK on this one about an hour before I started this. Quite horrible.

Comment: Well, it is error-prone and not elegant. Some years ago I had to fix a bug where someone commented out a line after an if without braces. It took me half a day to find out that the following statement now was inside the if scope for error.

Comment: I agree with Peter, use the auto format, you will be amazed by the number of problems that can be found by something simple as that. @Fatal I agree with the error proneness of not using braces even for single line if. I always use them. However, Robert Martin did have a point, he said he does not use braces at all since an if should only have one statement, otherwise it should have been refactored into a method. I think it takes a lot of discipline to code like that.

Answer (score 0):

The last `current = queue.peek();` should be redundant. The fact that `while(current != null)` "fixes" the problem suggest you have a `null` value in the list.

Comment: See my above comment about the peek. I've also checked thoroughly and none of the nodes contain a null element (besides the pointers to any nonexistent children, of course).

This same tree worked with my implementation of in/pre/postorder, so it should work with a queue...

Comment: Can you construct a simple self contained test to reproduce the problem?